# PHP page isn't loading since I added sleep

Tags: php, while-loop, sleep

I am trying to experiment with while loops, and I don't want my loop to wait after each loop. And when I attempted to do this with sleep, my page wouldn't load and after a while of waiting I finally got an internal server error. Thanks

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($i<1) {
echo "less than <br />";
sleep(1);
}
?>
```

Comment: You do know you're never interrupting the while loop so it basically always sleeps and doesn't return a response unless you're setting the output_buffering to 0.

Comment: You do realise that is an infinite loop? $i will always be lower than 1 since you *never* increment it.

Comment: And maybe you should enable php errors.

Comment: @Leo, yeah I was experimenting.

Comment: Make sure titles are accurate. What it *really* "adding sleeping" that caused the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop, change

```
$i = 0;
while ($i<1) {
  echo "less than <br />";
  flush();     // <-- You could add an explicit flush
  sleep(1);
  $i++;        // <-- But you really must increment $i
}
```